# react native touchable opacity border color change when clicked

Tags: react-native

[image]

hi guys, above that picture i got product's sizes and colors, when onpress i keep that pressed one in state.  i need to change it's border color or background color too. how can i do that? by the way i have to choose one size and one color

here is my color picker component

```
const colorPicker = () => {
    let colorPick = colors.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.colorPickerDetail}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: dimensions.width * 0.2,
              height: dimensions.width * 0.07,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setColorPicked(product[index].ColorCode);
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: dimensions.height * 0.01}}> {item} </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingHorizontal: dimensions.width * 0.025,
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        {colorPick}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: hey share your codes i will help you.

Comment: this is my code, thats the one im using for picker in image

Comment: ur problem looks basic , but i need to see the connection between the item and the product array , then i can help you

Comment: thanks for help but i figured it out :)